# Displace an object by the height of a rotating oval shape

Tags: constraints

[image]

What I'm looking for is if I rotate the round button, the lever should move up, and when the button down lever should come down, which constrain and how should I use it?. Any suggestions or help? Thanks

**I tried floor relationship, but instead of moving up and down it's moving to the side.**

[image]

[video](https://imgur.com/a/vmvSaGI?third_party=1#_=_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Floor* constraint exists to prevent an object moving to the 'forbidden' side of a given plane.

The *Srinkwrap* constraint might be more appropriate here:

[image]

Set up as above, first, the block is moved in XYZ to the nearest surface point of the target cam, and then is bullied back to its original XY by the *Limit Location*. With this geometry, that happens to work.

[image]

If the objects are given a common parent, the rig can be translated and rotated freely.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Geometry Nodes to make it work with any shape:

1. Create a single vertex mesh (Cube, merge at center)
2. Parent your plate to that vertex (not object), by selecting that vertex and then shift-click on the plate in the outliner and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.
3. Add a Geonodes setup to the single-vert object:

[image]

[image]